# Как в новом Visual Basic открыть web-страницу

Tags: visual-basic, visual-studio

Как в новом Visual Basic открыть web-страницу в этом же окне?
Помогите с полным кодом, нулевой в этом деле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это просто с помощью [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx):

```
Dim url As String = "http://hashcode.ru/"
Process.Start(url)
```